# Unable to pass data to a controller inside a component in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components, mddialog

I have following component

```
componentsModule.component('detailComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'detailTemplate.html',
    scope: {},
    bindings: {
        textParam: '='
    },
    controller: ['$mdDialog',  function($mdDialog) {
      this.textParam // this is undefined always
   }]
});
```

I am loading template in a dialog from other controller like this

```
$scope.textParam = tParam;
const parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
$mdDialog.show({
      template: '<detail-component text-param="$scope.textParam"></detail-component>',
      ariaLabel: 'detailComponentDialog',
      parent: parentEl
}).then((savedDatails) => {});
```

If I use binding as `@` then I get `$scope.textParam` as a string inside my controller in `this.textParam` but if I set binding as `<` or `=` then I get undefined

Comment: I have found a working answer here. I had to create a dialog controller to present the component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308651/angular-material-load-angularjs-1-5-component-into-mddialog